# Xamarin Forms - CustomRenderer Not Working After Navigating Away

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a custom renderer in my iOS Native code for my main page. It works perfectly fine when the app start up, and renders Navbar items using the iOS System icons which is what I want. However, if I navigate away from the main page, when I navigate back the `RightBarButtonItems` array only contains two uninstantiated objects, I put in a check (`RightNavItems.Title == null`) to continue when this was the case to see what would happen, and indeed the items are not rendered, if I navigate away and back again the app crashes since the `RightBarButtonItems` array is now empty.

Why is it that the toolbar items are uninitialised when navigating back to the main page? What is the proper way to deal with navigation in a custom renderer like this?

Here is the code for the custom renderer:

```
public class ItemsPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public new ItemsPage Element
    {
        get { return (ItemsPage)base.Element; }
    }

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    var rightNavList = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

    var navigationItem = this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;

    for (var i = 0; i < Element.ToolbarItems.Count; i++)
    {
        var reorder = (Element.ToolbarItems.Count - 1);
        var ItemPriority = Element.ToolbarItems[reorder - i].Priority;

        UIBarButtonItem RightNavItems = navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];
        if (RightNavItems.Title == null)
            continue;

        if (RightNavItems.Title.ToLower() == "add")
        {
            rightNavList.Add(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add)
            {
                Action = RightNavItems.Action,
                Target = RightNavItems.Target
            });
        }
        else if (RightNavItems.Title.ToLower() == "edit")
        {
            rightNavList.Add(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit)
            {
                Action = RightNavItems.Action,
                Target = RightNavItems.Target
            });
        }
        else
        {
            rightNavList.Add(RightNavItems);
        }
    }

    navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(rightNavList.ToArray(), false);
}
}
```

Comment: When you say "custom renderer" is this an actual Forms renderer of a View? I.e. you are showing `ViewWillAppear` of a view controller....

Comment: @SushiHangover it's an extension of the PageRenderer class. I have edited to include the full class.

Comment: Can you provide a sample so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have created an Example using a Xamarin template which exhibits the same behaviour: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0DfTqRedqa_RytZ_VL-n5rFUQ#Example

Comment: OK I will check it

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code snippet

```
var rightNavList = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
var navigationItem = this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;
for (var i = 0; i < Element.ToolbarItems.Count; i++)
{
    var reorder = (Element.ToolbarItems.Count - 1);
    var ItemPriority = Element.ToolbarItems[reorder - i].Priority;

    UIBarButtonItem RightNavItems = navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];
    if (RightNavItems.Title == null)
        continue;
                
    if (RightNavItems.Title.ToLower() == "add")
    {
        rightNavList.Add(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add)
        {
            Action = RightNavItems.Action,
            Target = RightNavItems.Target
        });
    }
    else if (RightNavItems.Title.ToLower() == "edit")
    {
        rightNavList.Add(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit)
        {
            Action = RightNavItems.Action,
            Target = RightNavItems.Target
        });
    }
    else
    {
        rightNavList.Add(RightNavItems);
    }
}

navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(rightNavList.ToArray(), false);
```

You change the item appearance from `title` to `icon` when first entering the page , however , when second entering the page , the condition `RightNavItems.Title == null` is true , so it jump out the loop without adding any item to the list , so `navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems` add a null array at last.

#### Solution

Modify as below

```
if (RightNavItems.Title == null)
{
      rightNavList.Add(RightNavItems); //add this line.
      continue;
}
```